# How to format reputation when Jon Skeet hits 1 million+ rep next year?

Tags: discussion, reputation, formatting

Based on [Jon Skeet's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) past reputation gain, he will hit 1 million some time in July next year. We have until then to decide on how to format his colossal reputation.

The choices for the short format of 1234567 are to continue the "k" magnitude:

> 1,235k

Or start an "M" magnitude:

> 1.235M

Which should we do?

---

FYI, if "k" is continued, and his (very steady) reputation growth holds, it will be approximately 75 years until an extra digit needs to be added to cater for 10 million rep, which is long enough time for us to not care (much).

Comment: I think that on reputation overflow, the user's reputation should be reset to 0. It's Jon's mistake that he's hitting 1 million. Me, for example, didn't do that mistake.

Comment: @MarounMaroun - even better if an *actual overflow happens* and his rep goes into *negative* <sorry Jon> :P

Comment: @mar Surely overflow would occur at `2,147,483,648`?

Comment: `-2,147,483,647`  reputation for Jon it is.

Comment: BTW at the current trajectory, integer overflow will occur some 16,000 years from now. Let's put that one on the back burner.

Comment: @Bohemian But but.. you should consider **all** possible scenarios!

Comment: Show the full value in marquee. Blinking, too, obviously.

Comment: @rob actually it's `-2,147,483,648` :)

Comment: I can't code, I just run around pasting random snippets of CSS in the hope it fixes the problem. ~Carry on!

Comment: As an aside, I don't think it's going to happen until about this time next year. My average rep gain per day is much less than it used to be.

Comment: The rep cap gets removed at 1 million, right? I'm sure I heard that somewhere...

Comment: @JonSkeet you must have misheard... I said "reduced" - as in, made lower... :)

Comment: I think at 1M stage, you really stop caring about how much reputation you have. 1.0M would work.

Comment: I propose `1 sk`. The only reference worthy of Jon Skeet should be himself.

Comment: Definitely not 1,235k. k is for thousands, and when you get to thousand thousands, it looks and sounds weirdly redundant. I see no reason why we can't just use the whole number and wrap the badges to a new line in the user card.

Comment: Knu - The problem with using Skeets is that by definition his rep is always 1 sk. It might be useful for other users though.

Comment: It certainly won't be M, because that's too obvious. Use [m](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87251/use-m-for-million-instead-of-m) instead, so Jon Skeet will have 1 milli reputation

Comment: I'm all for the marquee like you'd have on geocities pages circa 1998 :)

Comment: Can't we just delete Jon's account? That solves all problems and requires zero code change.

Comment: If you as a moderator don't know the answer, who shall answer then?

Comment: @jon well, your profile's rep graph (linked in Q) is a very straight line for the past 3 years

Comment: @Bohemian: It's about 230 a day - sometimes a bit more, sometimes a bit less. That's 369 days to get another 85K. Even at a more generous 275 per day, that would be 310 days. Way later than July.

Comment: Just show infinite "∞" as his reputation. Then the problem is fixed as well for when he reaches 1 billion.

Comment: There's actually [a user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) that will be passing Jon Skeet in about 10 years. And reaching 10M rep. much quicker than Jon.

Comment: @ram I doubt that very much. Top devs know that the relational database is a trailing edge technology whose days are numbered. In a few years, that understanding will become more widely known, and him being a one trick pony will derive less and less rep as interest in SQL dwindles (and I should know - I used to be a "database guy").

Comment: @Bohemian Overflows can happen at unexpected values.  I once experienced a real world overflow at 2332768, because somebody had decided that it was a good idea to store the last five digits of a seven digit number in a two byte integer.

Comment: Invent a new number called `JonSkeet` (abbreviation `JoSk`) with the following definition: "rapidly increasing positive integer greater than 1,000,000". Computer scientists can then start calculating `JoSk` instead of adding thousands and thousands of digits to π that nobody uses anyway.

Comment: You guys have a serious problem with Jon's rep :] Anyways, This one sounds better: `1.235M`

Comment: Has anyone asked what Jon wants?

Comment: I want to know why there isn't a jon-skeet tag on Meta for questions like this one.

Comment: The day Jon reaches 1M, Stack Overflow should just say *Game Over - Jon won*. And then the next day we delete everything and start at 0.

Comment: What about a badge for 1M+ reputation? I asked a question about if there is anything special about reach 1 million of course StackExchange moderators marked it as duplicate to this... So formatting or badge kind of the same thing?

Comment: "Based on Jon Skeet's past reputation gain, he will hit 1 million some time in July next year."  It's mid August, and he's at "967k".  Must be resting on his laurels...

Comment: According to my calculations, Jon Skeet should hit 1 million sometime in January or February 2018.

Comment: @DonaldDuck actually I came looking for this post just to post that...

Comment: @DonaldDuck looks like you are about to be right. He is at 999,106 today.

Comment: @joshmcode He just hit 999306 in 18hrs. The countdown should now begin 
 I believe :D

Comment: 999,536 - ah, the excitement! A gold badge for the first one to call the million?

Comment: `1,000,236`. Congrats Jon Skeet. Getting a 500 bounty is a classy way to jump over 1M rep.

Comment: Seems the earth is still spinning - phew! Just a brief power grid failure in the area I live in at 7am CET.

Comment: @Bohemian then change the datatype representing the reputation to like a short int and troll everyone with reputation greater than 32767

Comment: "1M rep ought to be enough for anybody" - Jeff Atwood, 1981

Comment: FWIW [cross-site duplicate at MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305775/165773) now is tagged status-completed and seems to describe a different format than in currently accepted answer

Answer (score 215, accepted):

**Follow the current format**

At 1m points, the display should be 1,000k, which stays in this fashion up until 9,999k at which point the display would change to 10m. (If that ever even happens).

This style would be inline with how a full points view is shown up until 10k, at which point it is switched out for the cleaner look, presumably due to the added digit.

Comment: Get to work, Jon!

Comment: Get to work, everyone :P

Comment: I heard that right before he hits 1M he's going to give 80% of his rep to the poor

Comment: @Hack-R I'm poor, i can haz reps?

Comment: 9,999 are 5 characters. 10,000 would be 6 characters which is too long so becomes 10k. 1,000k would be 6 characters too.

Comment: I consider this poor UX.  Nobody refers to a million dollars as "a thousand grand", and nobody says "1000k" when they mean a million.  Without a doubt, the correct thing to do is to display either 1.0m or 1.00m as soon as Jon hits 999 500.

Comment: @DavidWallace a [relevant XKCD](https://xkcd.com/558/) presents a counter-argument.

Comment: Using the logic @DavidWallace points out I don't understand why anything but 1M is being considered. DavidS - While the comic is funny it's just that, plus there is nothing to compare Skeet's rep to so, you can leave my daughter alone!

Comment: As far as I can see, the questions are - how many decimal places to show, and should it be `m` or `M`.  And I'm not going to comment on the reputation of anyone's daughter.

Comment: Wouldn't applying the XKCD comic argument cause a broader reconsideration of the reputation display?  There are already folks with, say, 10k reputation next to others with 10 reputation.

Comment: 1,000k? What the hell?

Comment: I agree with @DavidWallace. DavidS's xkcd ref is amusing, but not a great comparison imo. Unlike a billion (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billion), a million (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Million) is an unambiguous universal unit. That said, dev for 1,000K is probably much quicker and less likely to make bugs. If i was doing the dev, I'd do k's, if I was asking for the dev, I'd ask for 'M'. :)

Comment: Congratulations Jon. The time has come.

Answer (score 161):

I think it should just display "Oh Wow!".

Comment: Oh Wow! This is the answer.

Comment: Suppose he asks a question  and sets a 50 points bounty on it. Then how are we supposed to calculate ("Oh Wow!"-50), I hope the sign you used is an exclamation mark rather than a factorial.

Comment: @F.I.V leave his rep as "Oh Wow", and give the person who answered the bounty a badge for helping Jon instead of rep. problem solved.

Comment: If reputation is akin to karma, then according to the teachings of the Bhudda, 1M karma is technically the threshold for Nirvana. The indicator should therefore read "ascended".

Comment: Jon Skeet - Oh Wow reputation

Comment: Way back in the day there was a game that gave up listing how many monsters were in an army and just said, "Zounds..."

Answer (score 75):

### Replace it with a unicorn

It is, after all, tradition.

[image]

Comment: May I ask why this post got 2 upvotes, yet the doge one below got 6 downvotes?

Comment: @arin Unicorns have a certain cultural significance here that doge simply does not. For reference, that painting is the one SO gave to Jon back when he became the first person to reach 200k rep.

Answer (score 58):

Assuming no code changes, then what we get is (testing locally):

[image]

Note no commas. This is pretty configurable, but is currently:

- `>= 100000` => / 1000, `{0:##k}`
- `>= 10000` => / 1000, `{0:##.#k}`
- `>= 0` => `{0:##,##0}`

(with the full value in the title text, like usual)

So... is this a problem?

Note: we need to keep in mind internationalization; in Brazilian Portuguese, for example, "k" becomes "mil" and "тыс." in Russian - so the available space is not necessarily what you think if you're mainly used to Stack Overflow in English (but: we can control each language's formats separately).

Comment: A comma would be in keeping with current pattern, ie `1,337K`. "No code change" isn't very relevant, only convenient. I'll wager this level of rep wasn't considered when that formatting was coded.

Comment: Interesting fact I just noticed, in the spanish SO, Thousands are abbreviated as "mil", which could cause issues with the notation of "m" for million, [see here](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/172250/fazer-php-imprimir-nomes-em-determinadas-classes)

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre you mention Spanish, but you've linked to `pt`... did you mean `es`? I've checked the code, and it *looks* like `es` doesn't currently use a custom number formatter, which means it will be using `en`, so... `k`? If you mean `pt`, then it uses `mil` for thousands, and either `Mil` or `Mi` for million (depending on the amount of space available). Note that just like `en`, `pt` is not configured to use a different format for millions when rendering reputation

Comment: @MarcGravell nope, I actually meant Portuguese, I linked the correct SO site, but said the wrong name - I opened each different version to check the formats used so I mistyped :)

Comment: @Bohemian it is relevant in as much as making it clear and obvious what the default position is

Comment: we should just create our own unit of measurement, 1 mil rep == 1 skeet

Comment: @m0sa Even better: 1 skeet == how much reputation Jon Skeet has. That way, everybody's rep will *decrease* over time, creating a gigantic incentive to get more rep!

Comment: I think this calls for a userscript to convert everyone's rep to a metric skeet scale, ie nanoskeet, milliskeet

Comment: @m0sa : That is great idea. Like astronomical unit. When I forget the distance between sun and earth I quickly remember 1 AU.

Comment: You need to update your screenshot with your hat. Otherwise we can see it's fake.

Comment: @MrLister well, maybe, but that means I need to configure extra things on my local rig... I'm going to be lazy and say that I'm simulating what it will look like in July

Comment: I will be very impressed if @JonSkeet now learns Portuguese and tests out what happens when a user's reputation reaches 1M on pt.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 43):

Since we now have an accepted answer I think it's only fair we post the real correct answer...

[image]

Comment: Yes!  Only at -5 now :D

Comment: Wait... [meta effect](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339819/how-to-format-reputation-when-jon-skeet-hits-1-million-rep-next-year?cb=1#comment423021_339875) actually resulted in *upvotes*? ;)

Answer (score 39):

[E Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation), imo...

## 1.23e6

... and never worry about it again. Format string: `{0:0.##e0}`

Alternatively:  **1.23×10<sup>6</sup>**

Comment: Yeah, that'd be really fun.

Comment: Simple and elegant :)

Answer (score 15):

For consistency, use the same formatting approach as is used for the "people reached" number on the user profile pages.  Jon Skeet's impact is [currently displayed there](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) as "~179.2m".

So, presumably the rules have already been visited for when to use `k` or `m`, as well as [the internationalization concerns Marc noted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/339829/684617).

One argument against this route, though, is that the profile pages appear to display reputation in a manner inconsistent with that displayed in questions/answers.  For example, the profile page might display "2.3k" whereas reputation displayed below an answer would fully spells out "2,345".

Answer (score 10):

The first terrible format

> 1,235K

violates at least four typographic rules that are stipulated in various international standards.

- When numbers with many digits are divided into groups of three digits, neither dots nor commas shall be inserted between the groups. A thin space may be used to divide the groups.
- The prefix symbol for kilo (factor 10<sup>3</sup>) is a lower-case k not K. The capital K is the unit symbol for the kelvin.
- There shall be a space between the number and the prefix symbol.
- Prefix symbols (such as k) cannot stand alone without any unit.

Accordingly, the second terrible format

> 1.235M

violates only two of the above-mentioned rules.

Comment: For these reasons I think M is better as well. Whether or not it's what most people want.

Comment: The "k" vs "K" is moot - pretty sure the actual code correctly uses lower case "k". I'd love to see some references for the others, out of curiosity; for example, usage of commas is pretty normal as a group separator (and yes, I'm well aware of the reversal of the symbols between locales).

Comment: Please cite the standards? I'm pretty sure I see e.g. "12,345" in plenty of established newspapers. I don't really care so much for following standards that I don't know what are.

Comment: I really think it's within the domain of SO's tech writers whether to use "K" or "k." Not... whichever standard we are apparently violating. We could also use some other random icon and violate the standard that way.

Answer (score 10):

Jon "loses" more reputation in the average day than most users earn in *years*.

If it wasn't for the cap of 200/day, Jon would have well over **4 million reputation**.

In the average day, he earns `1004 rep` and but "keeps" only `289` of it.

[image: img]

Jon, if you want to "spread the wealth", feel free to shell out a few hundred rep per day as bounties on questions that you think are deserving!  (You can afford about 700/day without affecting your daily gain!)

I noticed this phenomenon while playing with a little "calendar of site activity" that I'm building... check it out here: [SEDE: **"CALENDAR VIEW" of your Site Activity**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/880291)...