# Where's my 24 (carat) hat?

Tags: support, meta, winter-bash-2016

So [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339819/how-to-format-reputation-when-jon-skeet-hits-1-million-rep-next-year), asked on Dec 19, hit pay dirt and was awarded a gold "Great Question" badge a couple of days ago.

But I don't have a "24" hat :)

What's up?

Comment: Mod world's problem ;)

Comment: Love the pun ;)

Comment: Looks like you have one now.

Comment: @canon yeah, just happened to luck out with hitting 10K views (great question) during the bash

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You **don't** earn hats with actions on Meta sites, unless the hat's description explicitly states it (like I Am Your Father). Meta Stack Exchange is the only exception to this rule. See the last paragraph of [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245123/295232).