# First member with 1 million rep

Tags: discussion, reputation

Our very own [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) will reach 1 million rep within the next 3 months. (Probably less if he continues to rack up bounties.) Are we going to celebrate this milestone? What should we do? We need to start planning a huge party. There isn't much left!

Comment: Wasn't that asked 6-8 days ago?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339819/1016716

Comment: You're going to have to rent a hall big enough to accommodate the Stack Overflow community.  Yes, even the 1-rep users.

Comment: (whistles innocently with SQL server console opened) You _sure_ he's going to hit a million rep?

Comment: @TimPost you SURE Jon doesn't have a backdoor into Stack's backend to make his rep untouchable? come on...

Comment: I don't understand the down votes. This is a legitimate question. Will there be pizza and ice cream? A bouncy castle? The public needs to know if we're going to plan accordingly.

Comment: And this could be an opportunity to get the _not a robot_ badge I want so hard.

Comment: I'm *hoping* it happens during either CodeMash or NDC London - it should be around then, anyway. It would be nice to have a lot of dev friends around at the time :)

Comment: Somewhat related: we have a `[party]` tag?

Comment: @code11 We do now.

Comment: I assume the downvotes are because you've punctured the inflatable elephant in the room.

Comment: @Patrice: He doesn't need a backdoor for that.

Comment: @Jon Looks certain to happen during NDC week then.

Comment: @Martin: Yup - Wednesday, unless there are bounties.

Comment: Note this is not a duplicate of the proposed question. I'm asking how SO is going to reward the **community**. @JonSkeet is rewarded with fuzzy warm feelings inside. That should be enough =p

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, there are bounties.

Answer (score 22):

There will be ... something. Can't give too many details yet, but yes, there will be something to celebrate the occasion shortly after it comes to pass.

Comment: Can you at least give some details?

Comment: @mega6382: no __[SPOILERS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ePC2.jpg)__

Comment: @Cerbrus Oh, I think [this spoiler](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/01/what-happens-when-you-reach-200k-reputation/) is much better.

Comment: I already know - at 999,999+, it wraps around to 1 again.

Comment: I'd much rather it wrapped around at 1,048,576. Much neater.

Comment: @MrLister Only a programmer thinks that 1,048,576 is a "round number"

Comment: @Code-Apprentice And an artist will think that 0 is the only round number. What is your point?

Comment: @MrLister My point is that the typical person considers powers of 10 rational numbers. As programmers, we prefer powers of 2. This is simply a sociological observation on my part.