# User reputation in answers appear differently than in the profile

Tags: feature-request, design, reputation, profile-page

Just came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6841479/7109869) from @JonSkeet and, in the reputation, just realize it appears **1219k**:

[image]

Why does it appear differently that in the user profile (**1.2m**)?

[image]

Personally, I find 1.2m more user friendly.

Comment: It shows as 1,218,648 also. It depends on where it's showing and how much room there is.

Comment: Related: [How to format reputation when Jon Skeet hits 1 million+ rep next year?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339819/2675154)

Answer (score 0):

Given that there are currently exactly two users with over 1 million in rep (and only 3 that are even within 100k of it), I don't think that this is that big of a deal.

Comment: Inconsistent design is not something to be waved away though, especially when it comes to statistics. It could be something trivial... it could be a bug in reusable code which might rear its ugly head somewhere that is a big deal.

Comment: There are three now.

Comment: There are five now. And others are almost there. Still not a huge number, but some consistency there would still be better.