# Congratulations VonC for reaching a million reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation, users, top-users

Today - Sunday, 29 November 2020, I just noticed that [**VonC**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) reached  1 million points of reputation on Stack Overflow.

[image: profile for VonC on Stack Overflow, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

**VonC** has a position of **Development Architect**  at **Softeam** at **CACEIS Paris, France**.

He has a diploma of Advanced Studies & Bachelor Engineer in computer science from [ESIAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telecom_Nancy).

He joined Stack Overflow in the year 2008 and has posted an astonishing 24,894 answers.

He is the third person on Stack Overflow as a whole to become a reputation millionaire.

I don't think I have had the chance to have VonC answer any of my questions, but I have definitely used his answers to learn something new.

It is an incredible milestone to achieve this because it takes a lot of effort, challenge, and patience in a daily routine to continue this process.

It inspires people like me and others to reach this stage.

So finally thanks VonC, congratulations and keep it up with this great job!!!!!!

Comment: And second millionaire from europe, no?

Comment: With 13,236 of the contributions tagged [tag:git] the key take-away is: Git is as confusing and finicky as it is popular. Thanks for tackling the former.

Comment: There will soon be a fourth millionaire. @BalusC has 964k rep.

Comment: `I don't think I have had the chance to have VonC answer for any of my questions` He just answered this one ;)

Comment: Where my git knowledge comes from: Git docs: 10%, VonC: 90%. Congratulations and thank you, VonC!

Comment: @10Rep Sadly, starting January first, 2021, I will automatically be the first millionaire of the [European Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union): that is one "first place" I hope Jon Skeet will reclaim soon.

Comment: This somehow isn't being celebrated as much as similar events for Jon Skeet and Gordon Linoff...

Comment: Plug in your User ID to see if [VonC has answered your question](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1337768/thank-you-vonc) on the Stack Exchange Data Explorer

Comment: @expressjs123 I think it's because of Thanksgiving.

Comment: Hey, didn't [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035) reach [a million reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400506) about three months ago? The rate at which one of our users gets a million rep seems to be speeding up. Anyways, congrats for reaching one million rep! P.S. I was just thinking that VonC might actually beat Gordon, but after taking a look at the daily reputation that VonC and Gordon get, it seems like that won't happen, at least for a few years.

Comment: @expressjs123 Well, but really, when Gordon Linoff got a million rep, we didn't celebrate it with a Stack Overflow blog post and a podcast from him as we did with Jon Skeet: we had a blog post and he had a podcast.

Comment: @VonC I don't understand what you mean. I do hope that you will surpass Jon Skeet so that we can stop worshipping him, but--no offence--it doesn't seem likely, given that the amount of rep that Jon gets every day is about the same as you do. Again, no offence for saying this.

Comment: @TheTechExpertGuy I am referring to Brexit (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brexit), unless an additional extension is decided before the end of this year. And yes, I will catch up with Jon, assuming our respective activities remain unchanged. That will occur in about... 22 years. Gordon will also catch up with Jon. Within the next 3 years.

Comment: And **60k** up-votes given... generous as well!

Comment: @TheTechExpertGuy [as we can see, by late next year, we'll have over four dozen million rep users.](https://xkcd.com/605/). OK, looking at the [rep page](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow) seems like we might get one or two next year. [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc) (#4 in the list) is a definite candidate [Darin Dimitrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov) (#5) is next. However, they got close to 30k rep this year, so at this rate they'll hit a million in two years time.

Comment: I wish to be the first millionaire from africa

Comment: @VLAZ Good joke. Well, Gordon Linoff seems to actually be in a bit of a sandwich. He's got a bit more rep than VonC, and a bit less rep than Jon Skeet, but take a look at the amount of badges he's got. Gordon's got 47 gold badges, 446 silver, and 559 bronze. Even VonC's got much more badges than he's got. VonC has 414 gold badges, about half of Jon Skeet's, 3469 silver, and 4061 bronze. (Fun fact: [BalusC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882) has *more* silver badges than bronze ones: He's got 3437 silver badges and 3417 bronze badges.)

Comment: Would love to see more curation/review action by them! 1 million rep, but only 300 downvotes over 12 years is not very heartening. Seems ...unlikely... that only 0.5% of all the content they've seen on the site in that time is worth downvoting.

Comment: With my 131 reps that's astonishing..I mean it took me forever to hit 131..lol..But i am working everyday to contribute as much as i consume from this site. Congrats VONC

Comment: There are many ways how people do contribute to the knowledge library. Asking, answering, voting (up, down, close), editing, ... not all give equal amount of rep or improve the content equally, but it's definitely a collaborative, worldwide effort of many people doing their bit and a certain lower number of "heroes" giving lots and lots of hours filled with great expertise. Maybe we should kind of celebrate all of us and be inspired by all of us (those that contribute positively to the library).

Comment: I have had the pleasure of VonC having answered on of my questions on git. Only a person with million reputation could be so descriptive with their answer. Considering how basic that question was, i couldnt beleive a guy with 500k reputation at that time, chose to answer my question. @VonC Embodies the spirit of stackoverflow.

Comment: How can somebody answer that number of questions!!!! I thought he is a SO employee!

Comment: @AminShojaei Actually--and I'm not trying to spoil the spirit of this rep milestone celebration--Gordon Linoff has the most answers of any SO user, but I'm sure maybe a few years from now, VonC will have more answers than Jon Skeet, and then Jon Skeet will become the third answerer on SO, after Gordon and VonC lol. Also--again, I'm not trying to spoil the party--Gordon will beat Jon in rep about 3 years from now, and 22 years from now, VonC will beat Jon in rep. Then Jon Skeet will never be worshipped like he is right now again, when he would become the third-in-line when it comes to rep.

Comment: @TheTechExpertGuy I appreciate the sentiment, but please refrain from any serial upvotes. They will be detected, and rescinded (cancelled) the next day anyway.

Comment: @AminShojaei There are no SO employees whose job it is to answer questions on Stack Overflow. *All* of the prolific answerers that you see are unpaid volunteers. So are all of the moderators.

Comment: And he is French!

Comment: @Muteshi "But i am working everyday to contribute as much as i consume from this site." In a very real way, consuming is also contributing. After all, what would this site be without visitors. It certainly increases the motivation of the answerers and editors and voters, knowing that there are millions of people out there benefiting from it.

Comment: How many reputation millionaires are there across all the stack sites?

Comment: @SpacePhoenix I guess none, as most other stack sites are much younger and have much less traffic

Comment: @SpacePhoenix You can see the per-site rep maxes here: https://stackexchange.com/leagues I think the closest is egreg on TeX. https://stackexchange.com/leagues/85/alltime/tex

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I thought [harrymc](https://superuser.com/users/8672) on Super User was the closest match. After all, harrymc has been around for 11 years, while egreg has only been around for 9 years.

Comment: @theT I mean you can look for yourself?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- If Stack Exchange Data Explorer could let me look at data from all SE sites, then I could use an SQL query to see which site has the user who has the closest reputation to 1 million (excluding Stack Overflow, of course). But I can't do that, and I don't want to waste my time looking at all of that stuff for an hour, so I'm just going to assume that you're correct.

Comment: @TheTechExpertGuy harrymc has less than half of egreg's rep ... that was only one click to check

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Yes, I know that now, but I didn't even know about egreg before I saw your post. Now I know that egreg has more than 800k rep, and I know--and of course, I also knew this earlier--that harrymc only has about 330k rep.

Comment: If the daily 200 cap was removed he would have 2m+ by now

Comment: VonC probably joined SO *before* Jon Skeet! His user ID is 6309, while Jon Skeet's is 22656. The date on their profiles might both say "12 years, 2 months" but I suppose at the time when SO was just starting, there were lots of new users every day, so that would fill in the gap for a few days between VonC and Jon Skeet.

Comment: @expressjs123 Actually, according to [this Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/692588/how-much-rep-would-i-have-if-there-were-no-rep-cap), he'd have 1,944,973, which can be rounded to 2m rep, but he wouldn't have *over* 2m yet. However, Jon Skeet would've had 4,763,362, which is 4.8m rep. Finally, Gordon Linoff would have 1,466,791, which is 1.5m, rep.

Comment: P.S. Sorry if I've posted too much about other high-rep users like Jon Skeet or Gordon Linoff. I know this is about VonC.

Comment: @Bhargav Rao♦ Sir why you remove `featured` Tag??

Comment: The question has been featured for 1 week. That's plenty long enough. It's time to get some new content rotated into the sidebar.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- [Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1346168) is a SEDE query that shows you the top users outside of SO, and it proves that egreg on TeX is the top user outside of SO.

Comment: @BalusC has 997k rep points now, he is so close to 1 million too :D

Comment: First from France 

Answer (score 644, accepted):

Thank you for your kind words.

In keeping with the spirit of the recent Thanksgiving, I am grateful to be of service, and for everything this community has taught me, and continues to teach me every day.

Be safe out there.

Comment: That `1000k` looks dope!!! Congrats!

Comment: `1000k`... so even SO itself couldn't figure out [the formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3758880/4755520) the right way[.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55680772/4755520)

Comment: A kind guy answered my question when I first come to docker several years ago, thx.

Comment: @Tomerikoo on iOS app it says `1.00m`!

Comment: They should change it to 1M. Or maybe add a platinum badge!

Comment: Congratulations! Something that I've always admired about you is the fact that you were involved in some of the tag cleanups, which I've never seen any other extremely high rep users do, so thanks for that!

Comment: A million points in 12 years is incredibly impressive. We all understand that points are waymarkers and it's not, ultimately, about the points. The big picture is the number of human beings you have helped. Very well done and thank you.

Comment: I hope we can all wait another 22 years, when VonC will beat Jon Skeet in rep and we can finally stop worshipping Jon Skeet. (You know, I'm a bit tired of everyone worshipping Jon Skeet.)

Comment: I enjoy your answers to questions tagged [go] and [git] (which I watch). Kudos for that!

Comment: Your guess was mid december, but you reached it before.

Comment: It's worth noting that when VonC says "every day" here, that is [not an exaggeration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122976/165261).

Comment: Thank you so much for contributing to this website I loved your answers 

Comment: Now it's 1002k!

Comment: @TheTechExpertGuy It's like interests. The more good stuff VonC puts on Stack, the more there is to upvote. With 24,914 Answers, it's really not a mystery that the reputation just keeps going up! :)

Comment: @Scratte Yeah, I know, it's not a mystery. Obviously VonC gets upvotes for the good stuff that he adds to SO; I guess everything that high-rep users seem to post is good stuff.

Comment: @VonC It's my pleasure to having an answer from you.

Comment: Congratulations, @VonC! Thanks for your help to the community!
Actually, I could have said that in French! _Toutes mes félicitations, @VonC!_

Comment: Congratulations, @VonC! I wanted to write about you as a topic starter from this post and unfortunately I forgot it.  Thanks for your help to the community!  You are great man!

Comment: is it true senior devs also google for basic stuff ? :D

Comment: @ayorgo How to format 1M+ rep [already discussed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339819/how-to-format-reputation-when-jon-skeet-hits-1-million-rep-next-year).

Comment: Congratulations on the milestone !!! Your answers have helped a lot. Looking forward to getting more answers from you

Comment: @Tomerikoo They already have a platinum badge but it's white; you can't see it.

Comment: @ScottMcNeany After 17 days, I have granted you an upvote on your comment :)

Comment: I'm proud of you, and proud that I meet you one day, ***Félicitations et bon courage pour la suite @VonC*** :)

Comment: @YCF_L Merci, et bonne continuation à toi aussi :-)

Answer (score 78):

`git commit -m "congrats VonC!"`

Comment: I also have one line of code: `continue;`.

Answer (score 20):

I want to thank VonC for his commited availability to help with ClearCase questions - a much less glamorous pursuit than git. Only a few ClearCase-minded people are here on SO (many of us - not of our own volition...) and there isn't much in the way of high reputation. But question after question (and I've had a few) - it's usually VonC's concise and useful answers which clinch it for me.

Thanks a Million!

Answer (score 13):

VonC! I remember when I started life as a ClearCase Administrator, I was just never quick enough with my answers...I can't believe you've continued at such a pace! Amazing effort, and thank you for all your help over the years :D

Answer (score 7):

`git pull VonC points`

jumping in on the bandwagon

**EDIT :**
(lets make this post more congratulatory than it was)

Congratulation VonC, this is from everyone who jacked up their git knowledge, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

To VonC:

> Thanks for [not leaving out python](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=5&tab=Relevance&q=user%3a6309%20%5bpython%5d) on your question answering journey, now I can relate!
>
> A third of [those answers are unsung](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A6309+%5Bpython%5D+score%3A0), *let them be sung!*

**Congratulations on your one-mil!** <sub>(Even if I'll have to pay for it digitally... nah, who cares!)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

> Congratulations VonC

Thank you so much. This is now a part of a programmer's life.
Keep Contributing.

Grow together. Take Love. Stay Safe.

Answer (score 4):

Congrats, VonC! Hope you help us further in the future.

Thanks to you, I started learning how to use Git, all because of this.

Let me just make `Congrats.txt`, and then:

```
git add Congrats.txt
git commit -m "Thanks and congrats, VonC."
git remote origin add (certain_repository_url)
git push
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

**Congratulations!** I was about to post this myself, people are so fast I didn't even find out this was even posted!

Comment: Please drop the obsession with votes. It's not constructive, not relevant to the question, and not appropriate. People are allowed and encouraged to downvote posts for any reason they like. I have already explained this *countless* times in now-deleted comments under this very post.

Comment: @CodyGray I either forgot about your comments or stopped checking the comments here by the time you posted a comment. Anyways, I hope it wasn't about me, but I still really don't understand why people downvote this stuff. I know these are only congratulatory posts which can be downvoted without reason, but actually *that*'s exactly the reason why they don't need to be downvoted. At least voting order has been restored to these congratulatory answers.

Comment: @The It wasn't about you specifically. I deleted some 20+ comments under this very post discussing votes. I can't tell you why people downvote these answers, either, because I am not inside everyone's head. But everyone has a right to downvote for any reason(s) they like, and precisely *because* we don't know, there's no point in posting comments about it. It just invites endless speculation, which ranges somewhere from pointless to unconstructive.